# Delooping a fibration sequence with loopspace fiber and finite CW complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibration

The following question is somewhat similar to a [previous one on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257493/the-inability-to-continue-a-fibration-sequence-even-when-a-delooping-exists), except that my application does not directly involve Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $K(G,n)$, and so I don't see the immediate need for $n$-simple maps as in the theory of Postnikov $k$-invariants.

Suppose that $\Omega T \longrightarrow F \longrightarrow E$ is a homotopy fibration sequence, where $T$ and $F$ are connected **finite** CW complexes.  Is there a quantification in some sort of obstruction theory for extending this sequence further to the right in the form $F \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow T$ ?  This is a 1950s-era topology question.

Of course, the original sequence extends further to the right as $F \longrightarrow E \longrightarrow B hAut(\Omega T)$.  First, this is by Stasheff's paper for finite CW complexes as the fiber and any CW base, working with products in the full topological category [Sta63]. Later, this is by May's simplicial upgrade to infinite CW complexes as the fiber, working in the compactly generated category [9.5, 9.8][May75].

In my application, $T$ happens to have the structure of a Lie group, but this is a happy accident of its dimension, and I'm hoping for an answer that can work independent of this fact.

[Sta63]: James D Stasheff, *A classification theorem for fibre spaces*, Topology 2, 1963

[May75]: J Peter May, *Classifying spaces and fibrations*, Memoirs AMS 1:155, 1975

EDIT: As suggested, I renamed the base space $B$ to $T$, in order to not confuse it with the classifying space functor.  Also, I added two citations.

Comment: (I rename $B$ to $T$ to avoid confusion) I think the only obstruction is factorizing action map $E \to BAut(\Omega T)$ through delooping of tautological action $T \to BAut(\Omega T)$ which is done by usual obstruction theory.

Comment: @Denis T. : Любезно, what is the explicit formula for this tautological action?  Does it it assume that $T$ is a topological group, say by pointwise-conjugating a loop by an element of $T$?  If so, isn't this instead a map $T \longrightarrow Aut(\Omega T)$?

Comment: @QayumKhan The tautological action is the one corresponding to the pathspace fibration $\Omega T\to P T\to T$ (morally it is the action of $\Omega T$ on itself by left(?) multiplication)

Comment: @QayumKhan DenisNardin is right, I mean just an application of classifying space functor to map $\Omega T \to Aut(\Omega T)$ representing left (more precisely, the side $\pi_1$ of base acts on fiber in your preferrable conventions) multiplication. Also possibly you want to use Moore loops for that to avoid some nuances with non-strictly associative actions etc.

Answer (score 6):

This question is addressed in the paper

*Ganea, T.*, [**Induced fibrations and cofibrations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1994424), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 127, 442-459 (1967). [ZBL0149.40901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0149.40901).

A first observation is that $\Omega T\to F\to E$ extends to the right if and only if it is induced from the based path fibration $\Omega T\to PT\to T$ by a map $p:E\to T$. In Section 2, various sufficient conditions for such a fibration to be induced are given.

Two sample results:

**Corollary 2.5:** Suppose that $\pi_q(E)\neq 0$ only if $m\le q\le n + m-1$ and that
$\pi_q(\Omega T) \neq 0$ only if $n\le q\le n + m-1$, where $n\ge m\ge 2$. If the Whitehead product pairing $W:\pi_n(\Omega T) \otimes \pi_m(F)\to \pi_{n + m-1}(F)$ vanishes, then $\Omega T\to F\to E$ is induced.

**Theorem 2.10:** Suppose $\Omega T$, $F$ and $E$ all have the homotopy type of aspherical CW complexes. Then $\Omega T\to F\to E$ is induced if and only if the image of the induced map $\pi_1(\Omega T)\to \pi_1(F)$ lies in the center.

Comment: I would be very interested in knowing the level of generality in which these results hold. Do they work, for instance, in any $\infty$-topos?

Comment: @MarkGrant : I appreciate the partial answer; however, my specific application (which I didn't specify in the question) fails to satisfy the connectivity hypotheses of your answer here and also the previously linked MathOverflow question.  Specifically, all of my finite CW complexes $T, F, E$ are non-simply connected and have homotopy groups in infinitely many dimensions.  My opinion is that the results in Ganea's paper are more-or-less a 'thickening' of the preexisting result on Eilenberg--MacLane spaces that he advances.